# Establishing Virtual IP failover on apache load balancer running Windows 7 OS

Tags: windows-7, load-balancing, virtual-ip-address

I am attempting to configure a fault tolerant, high availability load balancer cluster which operates on Apache's ModJK modules. And after some lookup on the current practices, i would like to adopt load balanncer failover methods using VirtualIPs.

However, as the machines are operating in Windows 7, it appears that popular VirtualIP failover solutions such as KeepAlived and UltraMonkey is no available as they are only supported on linux operating systems.

Are there any alternatives for VirtualIP failover solutions that caters to Windows 7 OS?